# List specific image sizes in Media Library as standalone images

Tags: php, wordpress

I added a new image size (500x500) in my functions.php and it's generated correctly in my uploads folder. I added a filter to be able to select it on the attachment page.

Additionally I would like to see this image (image500x500.png) as a standalone image in my media library, to be able to include it in a gallery with other image sizes too. (currently only 1 image size can be set for a gallery)

Any ideas?

Comment: In which image order you have to get different image sizes?

Comment: Do you see your image size in the Media Library under Display Settings > Size?

Comment: Where is Display Settings in my Media Library located?